# how to fill alpha with color?

Tags: libgdx

model changes color completely:

```
G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(new JsonReader());
Model model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("g3dj/model.g3dj", Files.FileType.Internal));
ModelInstance modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
modelInstance.materials.get(0).set(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(0, 0, 1, 1));
```

I want to replace only the alpha channel with blue color

(one model, many colors)

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain your goal and the problem you're encountering in more detail? With graphics questions, an image or two is often a great way to get your readers to quickly understand your situation.

Comment: Alpha channel and blue channel are separate things, not sure how you imagine filling the alpha channel with blue to work. The Warcraft II effect was probably more like: go into the sprite and look for "team color" pixels, and draw them with the team colors of the owning player. Try looking up "palette swapping" or "palette shaders" perhaps.